# Vsphere: Terraform apply not able to complete - hangs on creating VM

Tags: terraform, vsphere

**PROVIDER: VMWare vSphere**

Hi,
I am trying to create a new VM from the template using terraform. Since guest OS I use is in the guest OS support matrix of VMware, so I add the "skip_customization". However, when I do a "terraform apply". Terraform gets stuck on the creating the VM state and doesn't move forward.

**Terraform Version: 0.9.11**

**Terraform Configuration Files:**

```
# Configure the VMware vSphere Provider
provider "vsphere" {
  user           = "${var.vsphere_user}"
  password       = "${var.vsphere_password}"
  vsphere_server = "${var.vsphere_server}"
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
}

# Create a folder
  resource "vsphere_folder" "Terraform" {
  datacenter = "Datacenter"
  path = "DSM/Terraform"
}

# Create a virtual machine within the folder
  resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "test" {
  name   = "Terraform-test"
  folder = "${vsphere_folder.Terraform.path}"
  vcpu   = 2
  memory = 4096
  datacenter = "Datacenter"

  network_interface {
      label = "network"
  }
  disk {
     # Guest OS: Ubuntu Linux (32-bit)
     template  = "DSM/A/template"  
  }
   skip_customization = true
}
```

**Terrafrom Apply**

This is what I get after terraform apply: (it shouldn't take that long, and it won't stop if I don't terminate it)

```
... 
vsphere_virtual_machine.test: Still creating... (10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.test: Still creating... (20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.test: Still creating... (30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.test: Still creating... (40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.test: Still creating... (50s elapsed) 
...
vsphere_virtual_machine.test: Still creating... (21m20s elapsed) 
vsphere_virtual_machine.test: Still creating... (21m30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.test: Still creating... (21m40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.test: Still creating... (21m50s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.test: Still creating... (22m0s elapsed)
Interrupt received. Please wait for Terraform to exit or data loss may occur. 
Gracefully shutting down... 
stopping apply operation...
vsphere_virtual_machine.test: Still creating... (22m10s elapsed) 
Two interrupts received. Exiting immediately. Note that data loss may have occurred.
```

**Expected Behavior**

Finish creating and show message apply complete.

**Actual Behavior**

Terraform hangs on creating VM.

**Steps to Reproduce**

terraform plan
terraform apply

**Important Factoids**

Using user account with datacenter level permission access